# Combine array of objects into another array per table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api, javascript-objects

I have a checkout table from where I obtain the values to later send as an API POST request.
I've built two separate arrays and now I need to combine them, and I'm having trouble to achieve this.

This is my code:

```js
let orderItems = "";
let orderArray = [];
let prodsArray = [];
let datesObj = {};
let modifiersArray = [];
let comboMealsArray = [];
let modifiersObj = {};
let modifierID;
let modifierPrice;

for(var i = 0; i < jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item .wc-item-meta li").length; i++){//get modifier id and price from table

  modifierID = jQuery(".hidden-modifier-id").eq(i).text();//modifier id is hidden from frontend but obtainable
  modifierPrice = jQuery(".wc-item-meta .amount").eq(i).text();//each modifier price

  let removePriceSymbols = modifierPrice.replace("€","");
  let formatPrice = removePriceSymbols.replace(",", ".");
  if(formatPrice === ""){
    formatPrice = 0;
  }
  let actualModifierPrice = parseFloat(formatPrice);

  modifiersObj = {[modifierID]: actualModifierPrice}; //outputs: {2971: 1}
  modifiersArray.push(modifiersObj);
}

console.log(modifiersArray); // outputs: [{2971: 1}, {2972: 1.5}, {2972: 1.5}, {2971: 1}, {2972: 1.5}, 2990: 0}]

for(var i = 0; i < jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item").length; i++){//get order values from checkout table per row
  let prodsObj = {};
  let prodName = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > a").eq(i).text();//get prodName from table cell
  let prodQuant = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > .product-quantity").eq(i).text();//get prodQuant from table cell
  let prodDelivetyId = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > #delivety_api_id_field").eq(i).text();//get delivety prod api id from table cell
  let prodTotal = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-total > .amount").eq(i).text();//get prodTotal from table cell
  let removeQuantSymbols = prodQuant.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
  let removePriceSymbols = prodTotal.replace("€","");
  let formatPrice = removePriceSymbols.replace(",", ".");

  orderItems += prodName + "  " + prodQuant + "  " + prodTotal + "\r\n"; 

  let actualID = parseInt(orderNumber);
  let actualQuant = parseInt(removeQuantSymbols);
  let actualApiID = parseInt(prodDelivetyId);
  let actualPrice = parseFloat(formatPrice);    
  let prodTotalUni = actualPrice / actualQuant;

  //prodsObj.name = prodName;
  //prodsObj.id = actualID;
  prodsObj.api_id = actualApiID;
  prodsObj.count = actualQuant;
  prodsObj.price = prodTotalUni;
  prodsObj.modifiers = modifiersArray;

  prodsArray.push(prodsObj);
}
orderArray.push(prodsArray);
console.log(orderArray);
```

This is my table [chekcout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxHqM.png) and this is what my API response looks like:

```
{"2022-12-21":[{"api_id":2753,"count":1,"price":10.5,"modifiers":[{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2972":1.5},{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2990":0}]},{"api_id":2753,"count":1,"price":9.5,"modifiers":[{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2972":1.5},{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2990":0}]},{"api_id":2748,"count":1,"price":14.5,"modifiers":[{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2972":1.5},{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2990":0}]}]}
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
{"2022-12-21":[{"api_id":2753,"count":1,"price":10.5,"modifiers":[{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5}]},{"api_id":2753,"count":1,"price":9.5,"modifiers":[{"2972":1.5}]},{"api_id":2748,"count":1,"price":14.5,"modifiers":[{"2971":1},{"2972":1.5},{"2990":0}]}]}
```

I'm not quite sure how I would achieve this and I'm even having trouble explaning my problem correctly but hopefully you can understand by looking at my code/examples.

This is my table input structure:

```html
<table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--order-details shop_table order_details">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">Product</th>
                <th class="woocommerce-table__product-table product-total">Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a>Fried Chicken</a><span id="delivety_api_id_field">2753</span> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong><ul class="wc-item-meta"><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Side Dishes Options:</strong> <p>Rice<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2971</span> (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>)</p></li><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Side Dishes Options:</strong> <p>French Fries<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2972</span> (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>)</p></li></ul> </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>10,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>  </td>

</tr>

<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a>Fried Chicken</a><span id="delivety_api_id_field">2753</span> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong><ul class="wc-item-meta"><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Side Dishes Options:</strong> <p>French Fries<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2972</span> (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>)</p></li></ul>    </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>9,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>   </td>

</tr>

<tr class="woocommerce-table__line-item order_item">

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
        <a>Steak</a><span id="delivety_api_id_field">2748</span> <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong><ul class="wc-item-meta"><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Side Dishes Options:</strong> <p>Rice<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2971</span> (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>)</p></li><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Side Dishes Options:</strong> <p>French Fries<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2972</span> (+<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>)</p></li><li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Preparation:</strong> <p>Rare<span class="hidden-modifier-id">2990</span></p></li></ul>    </td>

    <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>14,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>  </td>

</tr>

        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Subtotal:</th>
                        <td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">34,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Shipping:</th>
                        <td>Local pickup</td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Payment method:</th>
                        <td>Multibanco</td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Total:</th>
                        <td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">34,50&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit after all comments

```
  let orderItems = "";
let orderArray = [];
let prodsArray = [];
let datesObj = {};
let comboMealsArray = [];
let modifiersObj = {};
let modifierID;
let modifierPrice;




for(var i = 0; i < jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item").length; i++){//get order values from checkout table per row
  let prodsObj = {};
  let prodName = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > a").eq(i).text();//get prodName from table cell
  let prodQuant = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > .product-quantity").eq(i).text();//get prodQuant from table cell
  let prodDelivetyId = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-name > #delivety_api_id_field").eq(i).text();//get delivety prod api id from table cell
  let prodTotal = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item > .product-total > .amount").eq(i).text();//get prodTotal from table cell
  let removeQuantSymbols = prodQuant.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
  let removePriceSymbols = prodTotal.replace("€","");
  let formatPrice = removePriceSymbols.replace(",", ".");

  orderItems += prodName + "  " + prodQuant + "  " + prodTotal + "\r\n"; 

  let modifiersArray = [];
  let prodMods = jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item").eq(i).find("li");
  for(let prodMod of prodMods) {
    modifierID = jQuery(".hidden-modifier-id", prodMod).text();//modifier id is hidden from frontend but obtainable
    modifierPrice = jQuery(".amount", prodMod).text();//each modifier price
  
    let removePriceSymbols = modifierPrice.replace("€","");
    let formatPrice = removePriceSymbols.replace(",", ".");
    if(formatPrice === ""){
      formatPrice = 0;
    }
    let actualModifierPrice = parseFloat(formatPrice);
  
    modifiersObj = {[modifierID]: actualModifierPrice}; //outputs: {2971: 1}
    modifiersArray.push(modifiersObj);
  }

  let actualID = parseInt(orderNumber);
  let actualQuant = parseInt(removeQuantSymbols);
  let actualApiID = parseInt(prodDelivetyId);
  let actualPrice = parseFloat(formatPrice);    
  let prodTotalUni = actualPrice / actualQuant;

  prodsObj.name = prodName;
  prodsObj.id = actualID;
  prodsObj.api_id = actualApiID;
  prodsObj.count = actualQuant;
  prodsObj.price = prodTotalUni;
  prodsObj.modifiers = modifiersArray;

  prodsArray.push(prodsObj);
}
orderArray.push(prodsArray);
console.log(orderArray);
```

I feel like you should learn a bit more about jQuery, there are things that you can do with it that really fits this situation (like searching for data in a given context). I'll maybe try to refine this even more at some point, but at least this works the way you intended it.
What I've done is create a second loop INSIDE the main loop, that iterates over each `li` element that represents a modifier, then jQueried the data you needed in that `li` element context.

Comment: my problem isnt that I have duplicate values on my modifiersArray, my problem is that modifiersArray contains the data of all modifiers and I need to correspond each modifier with their own prodObj.modifiers, so per product on the table I need to store each of its modifiers. I've updated my table image so it's easier to see how I identify each element of the table.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I focused more on the output data than what your code was actually doing. Is it mandatory for you that you fetch the modifiers apart from the other properties ? It would be easier to track which modifier corresponds to which api_id if they were both in the same loop. But if you tell me that you have to, i'll try rewriting your code to actually track the parent. tell me and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: It isnt mandatory to fetch the modifiers apart from all other properties, I did it that way because if I were to fetch the modifiers on the same For Loop I wouldn't get all the values. But if you can make it happen by corresponding each modifier to the api_id, that would probably be the best option.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, let me give it another try.

Comment: Could I get an example of your input structure ? Just to be sure how the modifier relates to the item

Comment: I've addded a print screen of my input structure at the end of my question. Hope thats what you need.

Comment: Sorry when I mean Input structure, i was speaking HTML : I'd like to see the whole `.woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item` div.

Comment: Updated with the whole table structure

Comment: Edited my answer, this snippet works the way you wanted it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @crimsonfreak it sure works now. Great answer, really simplified my code :)

Comment: Glad to help. Did you understand what i've done?

Comment: Yes I did, you've taken my separate For Loop where I was fetching the modifiers data, put it inside the general data For Loop and made it so that for each `jQuery(".woocommerce-table__line-item.order_item").eq(i).find("li");` adds the modifiers :)

Comment: Right, and most importantly, once you have the li, you call `jQuery(selector, context) ` to retrieve the ID and the price from that particular li only.